# Derivation of integral Laplace Transform property

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I stumbled across a property of the Laplace Transform that can transform an improper integral of a product of 2 function.

$$\int_0^{\infty} fg = \int_0^{\infty} \mathcal{L}(f) \mathcal{L}^{-1}(g)$$

This is very interesting and you can even use it to compute the dirichlet integral extremely easily:

$$2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx = 2\int_0^{\infty} \mathcal{L}(\sin(x))\mathcal{L}^{-1}(x^{-1}) = 2\arctan(x) \bigg\rvert_{0}^{\infty}=\pi$$

A pretty neat tool! But how would I go about proving that this is true? I've searched around but haven't found anything about this and can't even find the original place I first learned about this property.

Comment: You forgot the differential after the integral

Answer (score 0):

A rigorous formulation of the identity that is easy to prove states that $$ \int_0^{\infty} ({\cal L} f)(s) g(s) \ ds= \int _0^{\infty} f(s) {\cal L}(g)(s) \ ds$$

(Your version  reduces to this one when you symbolically replace $g\to {\cal L}(g$).

**Sketch of proof.**

The proof begins by re-writing the LHS as

$$ \int_0^{\infty} ({\cal L} f)(s) g(s) \ ds = \int_{s=0}^{s=\infty}\left (\int _{x=0}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-xs} g(s) dx\right) \ ds$$

and then swapping the roles of the two dummy variables of integration to convert it into the RHS.